# Flash piece doesn't display in FF

Tags: flash

http://incitoconsultants.com/test/

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're referring to the "intro" at the top of the page (beneath the menu), it looks fine on FF 3.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the absurdly large flash size. I'm noticing a large horizontal scrollbar in firefox 3.5.2 as well as no flash rendering.

Comment: I mean flash declared size, in the swfobject's instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

oops... it's because I moved some scripting into the body instead of the head tag.